# How can I limit the number of files that can be picked in react-native-document-picker

Tags: android, react-native

I wish to limit the user to select upto 5 files at a time when picking multiple files using react-native-dockument-picker's API "DocumentPicker.pickMultiple".

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/blob/master/index.d.ts, there doesn't seem to be option for limiting the max number of file user can select.

```
interface DocumentPickerOptions<OS extends keyof PlatformTypes> {
  type: Array<PlatformTypes[OS][keyof PlatformTypes[OS]]> | DocumentType[OS];
  mode?: 'import' | 'open';
  copyTo?: 'cachesDirectory' | 'documentDirectory';
}
```

There is only option to limit the type of file to pick.

You could try checking the response array and prompt users to retry picking files tho. Something like

```
const respList = await DocumentPicker.pickMultiple(options);
if (respList.length > 5) {
  // prompt user to retry
}
```

There is another library [react-native-file-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-picker), but it is old and doesn't receive a lot of usage so it is not really recommended.